# Hmisc package cannot loaded

Tags: r, package, hmisc

I installed Hmisc package but I am getting the following error shown below? How can I diagnose and fix this problem?

```
library(Hmisc)
Warning message:
"package 'Hmisc' was built under R version 3.3.3"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Hmisc'
Traceback:

1. library(Hmisc)
2. stop(gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s", sQuote(package)), 
 .     call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

Comment: Works with me. What OS is it? Can you give us more information, such as the output of `sessionInfo()` just before loading the package?

Comment: Hello, I am working under Jupiter iin a R notebook.

Comment: Maybe you could try `install.packages("Hmisc", type = "source")`, since that version of `Hmisc` seems to be very old.

Answer (score 1):

After seting the library the RStudio session using by setting the library path `.libPaths("C:../../Rpackages")` the problem is resolved.